# Wordpress Auto Page insertion in db when theme activated

Tags: wordpress

I want to add dummy pages (like typography) into the database "wp_post" table which contain textual information about the theme when someone install and activate my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hooks which you can call to insert pages.

1- after_switch_theme hook is called when you switch theme (available if your wp version > 3.3.0 ) [hook reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

2- wp_insert_post is used to create pages/post (more documentation at [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post))

Below code will be in your theme functions.php

```
<?php
function myactivationfunction($oldname, $oldtheme=false) {

}
add_action("after_switch_theme", "myactivationfunction", 10 ,  2);
```

Reference : [here explained in more details regarding activation and deactivation of theme](http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/2011/01/activationdeactivation-hook-for-wordpress-theme/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dbDelta( " YOUR QUERY " );` to insert the page